# Riddle: I am a mollusc

Tags: riddle, word

I am a mollusc

Remove my first, and I'll make you quite fast

Now remove my second, and you won't feel best

Now remove my third, and you'll get a square seven

Now remove my fourth, and it's lost

What am I?

Comment: Intriguingly, seems to have two possible valid answers!

Comment: @JosephDoggie - It's quite remarkable how well both answers fit. If it wasn't intentional OP should pretend it was.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are a

> SNAIL

because

> A snail is a mollusc.  A nail will hold you in place.  To ail is to be sick.  IL can be read as $49=7^2$ in Roman numerals if you adapt the prefixing rules.  L is a loss.

> I started with the L for a loss, then IL was clear and indicated the right track.

Comment: I don't quite get the nail one. The question says that it should make you fast, but a nail stops you?

Comment: @TLEontest77: Not fast as in quick, but fast as in [sense 1 (adj/adv) here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fast)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. +1 for a great answer!

Comment: @TLEontest77: Think of the verb _fasten_.

Comment: @TLEontest77 "Fast" is a great example of a Janus word.

Answer (score 24):

You are a

> Slug

Because

> -1: If you "lug" something, it's getting moved
>  -2: If you feel "ug", you're not feeling well
>  -3: "g" is the 7th letter of the alphabet
>  -4: There's nothing left!